# How can i identify an application flashing in windows taskbar in Testcomplete?

Tags: testcomplete

I need to verify if my application window flashes in the windows taskbar.Is there anyway to do that in TestComplete?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no a straightforward way to do this. The only thing I can suggest is to save an image of the taskbar item before it should start flashing and then compare the actual image with the saved image. If the images are different, the window caption is flashing.